# Deleting an Environment Variable from all users on Windows

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I need to know if there is any way to delete all the instances of a given environment variable, this means from all users and from the system itself.

The problem is about a software update.
I need to keep installed a software in 2 versions, the old and the newer one.
During the go live weekend i need to make sure that the OLD Version environment variable is deleted from the system (User and system) and just create the new one.

The problem is that i can log in the system with the admin user but not with the real user, so if he has the environment variable in his profile is when i have the problem.

Is there any way/soft for this purpose?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System variables are stored in registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and affect all users, so you have to delete unwanted variable only once.

User variables are in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`, but HKCU is actually just a mounted key from `HKEY_USERS`. So if you have administrative privileges, then you can access other users' enviromental variables by editing `HKEY_USERS\S-[something]\Environment`.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for answering. The problem is this "something" i can't make a script for it, as this "something" may be different from one computer to another, and in addition if there are 2 users, it may appear two times in the registry. Rigt???????   This is why maybe "deleting" all the keys with the env-var name may be a solution.

Comment: change it once, export the keys and import them on the other pc's.

Comment: Thanks, finally im doing it by navigating and cleaning the `HKEY_USERS\S-[something]\Environment` manually

Answer (score 0):

Created this ps cmdlet if you wanna remove a specific environment variable for a specific user

```
function Remove-EnvironmentVariableForUser
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $User,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Variable
    )

    Set-StrictMode -Version 'Latest'

    $AdObj = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($User)
    $strSID = $AdObj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
    $Sid = $strSID.Value
    Assert-NotNull $Sid

    $Path = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$Sid\Environment"

    $Property = Get-ItemProperty $Path -Name $Variable -ErrorAction Ignore
    if($Property) {
        Write-Warning "Removing $Variable property on path $path from user $User"
        Remove-ItemProperty $Path -Name $Variable
    }else{
        Write-Host "No such Variable exists"
    }
}
```